# Abbreviation of/ Abbreviation for

Tags: grammar

Hello which one of following sentences is correct? which one is more native and more use than the others?

Dr is **an** abbreviation **for** the word Doctor.

Dr is **the** abbreviation **for** the word Doctor.

Dr is **an** abbreviation **of** the word Doctor.

Dr is **the** abbreviation **of** the word Doctor.